# OpenSearch Index creation issues

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch, spring-data-opensearch

We are migrating our app from ElasticSearch v7.6 and OpenSearch v2.3. So in that process, we first created the index template in OpenSearch (2.3) cluster using the definition  below -

```
{
  "order": 0,
  "index_patterns": [
    "note-management-1.0-*"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "max_ngram_diff": "10",
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "ngram_filter": {
            "type": "ngram",
            "min_gram": "1",
            "max_gram": "10"
          }
        },
        "normalizer": {
          "keyword_normalizer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ],
            "type": "custom"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "text_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "ngram_filter"
            ],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard"
          }
        }
      },
      "number_of_shards": "5",
      "number_of_replicas": "2"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "owner": {
        "copy_to": "permissionToView",
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "lastModifiedDate": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "contentReadOnly": {
        "index": false,
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "lastModifiedBy": {
        "index": false,
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "readOnly": {
        "index": false,
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "title": {
        "search_analyzer": "standard",
        "analyzer": "text_analyzer",
        "type": "text"
      },
      "permissionToView": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "version": {
        "index": false,
        "type": "long"
      },
      "content": {
        "search_analyzer": "standard",
        "analyzer": "text_analyzer",
        "type": "text"
      },
      "tags": {
        "normalizer": "keyword_normalizer",
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "noteType": {
        "normalizer": "keyword_normalizer",
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "viewers": {
        "copy_to": "permissionToView",
        "index": false,
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "createdDate": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "externalObjects": {
        "dynamic": false,
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "displayName": {
            "normalizer": "keyword_normalizer",
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "id": {
            "normalizer": "keyword_normalizer",
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "type": {
            "normalizer": "keyword_normalizer",
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "usersByPinned": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "deleters": {
        "copy_to": "permissionToView",
        "index": false,
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "id": {
        "index": false,
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "outcome": {
        "index": false,
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "editors": {
        "copy_to": "permissionToView",
        "index": false,
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  },
  "aliases": {
    "note-management-1.0": {},
    "note-management": {}
  }
}
```

The index `note-management` wasn't yet been created in OpenSearch, and the expectation was that once the application created the first document based on the pattern created above, the index would be implicitly created.

The application was able to create the index and documents, but we could not retrieve them using the existing app because the queries were malformed according to OpenSearch.

We then deleted the implicitly created index and created it manually using the index created earlier in ElasticSearch v7.6. After that, the application was able to both index/query documents without any issue.

For the queries used by the application and the index that is generated using the spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch libraries, the problem seems to be that when the application creates the index, it does not follow the format and conventions used by OpenSearch pattern, and this causes the index to be created with incorrect format, which later cannot be queried.

Would be grateful if some expert could give us some pointers as to why this is happening and how to fix this issue.

As an example, when we created the index using spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch 2.4.11, the implicit index had the definition as -

```
{
  "note-management" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "_class" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "content" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "contentReadOnly" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "createdDate" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "editors" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "lastModifiedBy" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "lastModifiedDate" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "noteType" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "owner" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "readOnly" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "version" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1676061494880",
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "udj4QFKzSLSRyo8laD7vJA",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "135238227"
        },
        "provided_name" : "note-management"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which was wrong.

So we had to delete this index and manually create it with the correct definition as below -

```
{
  "note-management" : {
    "aliases" : {  },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "content" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "text_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer" : "standard"
        },
        "contentReadOnly" : {
          "type" : "boolean",
          "index" : false
        },
        "createdDate" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "deleters" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "index" : false,
          "copy_to" : [
            "permissionToView"
          ]
        },
        "editors" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "index" : false,
          "copy_to" : [
            "permissionToView"
          ]
        },
        "externalObjects" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "dynamic" : "false",
          "properties" : {
            "displayName" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "normalizer" : "keyword_normalizer"
            },
            "id" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "normalizer" : "keyword_normalizer"
            },
            "type" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "normalizer" : "keyword_normalizer"
            },
            "usersByPinned" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "index" : false
        },
        "lastModifiedBy" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "index" : false
        },
        "lastModifiedDate" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "noteType" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "normalizer" : "keyword_normalizer"
        },
        "outcome" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "index" : false
        },
        "owner" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "copy_to" : [
            "permissionToView"
          ]
        },
        "permissionToView" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "readOnly" : {
          "type" : "boolean",
          "index" : false
        },
        "tags" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "normalizer" : "keyword_normalizer"
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "text_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer" : "standard"
        },
        "version" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "index" : false
        },
        "viewers" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "index" : false,
          "copy_to" : [
            "permissionToView"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "provided_name" : "note-management-1.0.0",
        "creation_date" : "1676062153821",
        "analysis" : {
          "filter" : {
            "ngram_filter" : {
              "type" : "ngram",
              "max_ngram_diff" : "10",
              "min_ngram_diff" : "1"
            }
          },
          "normalizer" : {
            "keyword_normalizer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "type" : "custom"
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : {
            "text_analyzer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase",
                "ngram_filter"
              ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "RGYrVMtvSFWrSF1GwxuWKw",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "135238227"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data Elasticsearch is not built against or tested with OpenSearch libraries or servers.

You might want to check out the [spring-data-opensearch](https://github.com/opensearch-project/spring-data-opensearch) project which is based upon Spring Data Elasticsearch but uses OpenSearch libraries for the communication with the server.

Comment: Thanks so much for the pointer, sir. I would take a look at it.

Comment: Hello @p-j-meisch sir, wanted to check with you about the version of spring-data-opensearch client library that we should be using with OpenSearch v2.3.0? Is it fine to use 1.2.x or 1.1.x or should we use some earlier versions? Would be grateful if you please let me know.

Comment: I don't work on spring-data-opensearch, I am responsible for Spring Data Elasticsearch. You'll have to ask the people from spring-data-opensearch